# Facebook api feed error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

From yesterday I cant access Facebook posts from public groups:

I used

```
https://graph.facebook.com/102789269789238/feed?fields=id,from,message,to,updated_time,created_time,actions&since=1522912751&limit=20&access_token=(here is my access token)
```

but it shows error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '102789269789238' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "Dgt4fq250vZ"
   }
}
```

I cannot see any changes on facebook developer.

Comment: What kind of access token are you using? Are the conditions the documentation for reading a group feed mentions met?

Comment: I was using app token for 4 years

Comment: Well that is not possible any more, you will need to use a user access token of a group admin that granted your app the necessary permission.

Comment: Also for public groups? Where did you find that change?

Comment: Where did you _not_ find it, are you seriously saying you have not bothered to check the documentation yet?

Comment: I checked documentation but I cannot see things you mentioned.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/group/feed: _“A User access token for an Admin of the Group with the following permissions: user_managed_groups”_

Comment: I see now, but I cannot find out any api version change on 4.4.2018 when it stopped wokring. I know 12.4.2018 should be change just to version 5 which has this comment.

Comment: Some endpoints still accepted an app access token for certain operations, if the app had the required permissions granted by a user earlier, but with the whole current data breach/privacy “scandal” Facebook is very busy plugging such loopholes. _That_ they are currently not documenting properly (because it’s rather happening in a hurry), but the general change regarding who can access group data and how was announced a long while ago.

Comment: My app has stopped working too. I have the user_managed_groups permission as well. Facebook has limited access to apps which they deem are not active

Comment: I just have requested your link: it works. But when I do the same in the graph explorer - it does not (with the same token).

Comment: Same problem here, but, I´m admin of a group, and I can´t read the group endpoint. Got the same error even having the user_managed_groups permission

Comment: so, is the solution now to submit the app for review?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

> apps currently accessing Events and Groups APIs will lose access today